# Python ImportError: No module named resource

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm working with a Google App Engine project and within the project I am unable to use this import:

```
import resource
```

I receive this error:

```
ImportError: No module named resource
```

However, if I fire up the terminal and run this code it works fine:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import resource
```

The root folder of the project does not have an **_*init*_**.py file which is what many of the  other answers suggest. I use Aptana 3, OSX 10.8.2 and Python 2.7.3.

**Why would the import not work in my website, but does work in the interpreter?**

Comment: Are you sure Google App Engine runs with the same version of Python?

Comment: Yes, its using /usr/local/bin/python2.7, and when I use that full path for the interpreter I'm able to import resource

Comment: Make sure your pythonpath is properly configured to include the dir in which GAE lives. If it is not, use `sys.path.append('path/to/GAE/')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put `resource.py`, or the folder `resource` in your application's directory. GAE uses a different interpreter and therefore doesn't have the modules you installed on your computer.

Comment: why wouldnt I have that?